# Не получается избавиться от исключения ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Вопрос следующий: у меня есть активы и серийные номера к ним. Когда количество серийных номеров больше или равно количеству активов, программа работает корректно. Ниже пример кода, где я прохожу по каждому активу в цикле и присваиваю ему серийный номер. У 1 актива должен быть только 1 серийный номер:

```
String[] arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers = contractPosition.getSerialNumbers().split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < (contractPosition.getByElement() ? contractPosition.getQtyRemain() : 1); i++) {
  Asset asset = metadata.create(Asset.class);
  asset = templateService.getEntityWithAppliedTemplate(asset);
  asset.setSerialNo(arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers[i]);
}
```

Проблема возникает тогда, когда количество серийных номеров вводится меньше, чем активов. Тогда и выбрасывается ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Я пока дошел до такого примитивного решения, но оно меня не устраивает:

```
if (arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers.length < contractPosition.getQtyRemain()) {
    asset.setSerialNo("");
} else {
    asset.setSerialNo(arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers[i]);
}
```

При таком решении, если количество серийных номеров меньше, чем количество активов, то для каждого актива в поле "Серийный номер" будет пустая запись. Мне же нужна следующая логика: если активов 3, а серийных номеров, например, 1, то для первого актива серийный номер запишется, а для двух других нет - у них будет пустая запись в этом поле.
Как мне это сделать?

Comment: смотря что вы понимаете под пустой записью, `null`? тогда делайте `asset.setSerialNo(null);`, какая проблема? но вы же вполне можете построить логику программы таким образом, что `""` и будет считаться "пустой записью", такое решение тоже не редкость и даже имеет свои преимущества, например отсудствие необходимости в проверках на `null`

Comment: `if (arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers.length >= i) {`

Comment: @Eikthyrnir что `asset.setSerialNo(null)`, `что asset.setSerialNo("")` работают одинаково. Вопрос не в этом. Моя логика в принципе некорректно работает: если серийных номеров меньше, чем активов, то во все активы в качестве серийных номеров будет пустое значение. А нужно сделать так, чтобы для активов, для которых НЕ хватило серийных номеров, записывалось пустое значение. А для остальных активов серийные номера записывались)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy у меня при этом же условии else срабатывает. А можно сделать так, чтобы если `arrayOfStringsSerialNumbers.length < i `, то не вылетал ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, а серийные номера все-таки записывались для части активов?

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, с запоминанием количества активов в отдельной переменной, и использованием тернарного оператора.

```java
String[] serialNumbers = contractPosition.getSerialNumbers().split("\n");
int assetCount = contractPosition.getByElement() ? contractPosition.getQtyRemain() : 1;
for (int i = 0; i < assetCount; i++) {
  Asset asset = metadata.create(Asset.class);
  asset = templateService.getEntityWithAppliedTemplate(asset);
  asset.setSerialNo(i < serialNumbers.length ? serialNumbers[i] : "");
}
```